# Problem with partioning my drive [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted, resize

I am only running ubuntu 14.04 on my system. I am trying to partition my drive using Gparted but it does't allow me to resize my drive.

Here is what I did:

1. Run Gparted
2. Select my current partition. [partition: /dev/sda1, File System: ext4, Size: 694 GB, Unused: 503 GB, Flags: boot]
3. Select resize

At step 3 it does not allow me to resize. I cannot drag the bar or type in my free size box.

What should I do to create a new partition?

Comment: First of all keep a backup of your data just in case something happens when your partitioning the drive. Attempt the same process but on a live CD - You cannot modify the partition if it is mounted and in use. Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Thanks! It is mounted and in use. So do I have to do a fresh install all over again?

Comment: No that shouldn't be necessary. Insert and boot from a live CD/other boot media that you can use gparted on (the ubuntu live CD does have this but you can use any boot media that has it) and then perform the same operations. Because the HDD isn't mounted and in use, doing the same procedure that you described should work in theory. I would heavily advise for backing up any important data as it can be wiped if you do something wrong.

Kind regards, jkrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will back up all the necessary data and give this a shot :)

Comment: Glad to help. If that was the solution it would be perfect if you marked this as an answer to close the thread. Hope all goes well mate! @Nafio Nabi

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the assumption that you are trying to modify the partition which you are booted off and currently using `(/dev/sda1)`, from what you described. Gparted won't allow you to modify a partition that is mounted and in use.

To modify your `/dev/sda` partitions you can boot from a live CD or other boot media that has Gparted installed on it (your Ubuntu live media will have it installed already) and perform the same procedure that you mentioned in your question. In theory this should work absolutely fine because the `/dev/sda` partitions shouldn't be in use.

Before going ahead with this I highly advise to `**back up any data that you need**` as it may be lost if you do an operation incorrectly when modifying the partitions.

Kind regards,

jkrix